# If I wear dirty clothes, then wear clean clothes and do wadu, am I considered pure?

Tags: salat, wudu, taharah, salat-qada

Suppose I wear clothes having dried urine on them then after some time I change the clothes and wear clean clothes and do Wudu. Now, will I be considered pure? If not then what do I have to do? And if I am not considered pure will I have to pray the Salat that I prayed in that state again Qada?

Comment: According to Ibn Uthaymeen if you forgot to make wudu and then you remember it you have to pray again. If your clothes were dirty and then you find it out then you don't have to pray again.

Answer (score 1):

You would be considered as a pure person if you are not sure that the dried urine definitely has toughed your body (by things like water...). Of course as a significant ruling, saying prayer by Najis (impure) clothes is not true/accepted. For more precaution, you'd better wash your clothes and go to bathroom and wash yourself to be certain regarding this issue (to be clean/pure).